# nodejs click like on instagram post

Tags: javascript, node.js

i know this is the dumbest question of them all, but how would you go about making an app that clicks like on an instagram post? Without using the instagram api.

Would i use a headless browser or is there someway to do a post request and do it?

Comment: I have similar experience, but rather I use a Tampermonkey script in Chrome, which simply uses `element.click()` to like a post. Looking forward to see where this goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a POST request to like an image:
POST https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/${ID}/like/

However: The POST request requires a csrftoken & sessionid token to be passed in.
Therefore, you would have to make a GET request to the url you want, parse out the csrftoken as well as a sessionid and then send that as a request. From playing around with cURL, this is the simplest request that works:

```
curl 'https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/POST_ID_GOES_HERE/like/' -X POST -H 'cookie:csrftoken=CSRF_TOKEN_GOES_HERE; sessionid=SESSION_ID_GOES_HERE;' -H 'origin: https://www.instagram.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-csrftoken: CSRF_TOKEN_GOES_HERE' -H 'referer: https://www.instagram.com/' -H 'authority: www.instagram.com'
```

Luckily, these are all stored as cookies. Meaning: If you logged in using a browser (headless or otherwise), you could grab the cookies off of there and then make POST requests using whatever framework you're most comfortable with.

Otherwise you could do the whole thing in a headless browser if you want to.

Comment: Teach me your ways yoda, i want to learn. How did you find out it requires csrftoken and sessionid. Also where did you get the post request link? I was playing around with the insta api and website and didnt get close to where you are.

Comment: Open up the chrome debugging tools and look at the network tab. You can see the requests being made. You can right click a request and select 'copy as cURL'.

Comment: Thats so simple im surprised i didnt know this earlier. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I will use headless browser to do it like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)